# Devise sign up not working anymore - is there a conflict with users controlller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller, devise, user-registration

I'm in trouble, my devise sign up doesn't work anymore...
it worked perfectly fine until i guess, i created a users controller (to edit user show, with photo, nickname etc...).
Is there any chance there could be a conflict ?
Anyway, I don't understand, since I made an app with the very same schema and I had no difficulties.

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :trainings

  root to: 'pages#home'

  get 'home', to: "pages#home"
  get 'dashboard', to: 'pages#dashboard'
  get 'tutorials', to: "pages#tutorials"
  get 'classads', to: 'pages#classads'

  get 'profile', to: 'users#show'

  get 'sessions', to: 'trainings#sessions'
  get 'my_trainings', to: 'trainings#my_trainings'
end
```

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user

    if @user.update(user_params_update)
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:nickname,:address,:email,:tel,:photo, :old, :description, :password)
  end

  def user_params_update
    params.require(:user).permit(:nickname,:address,:email,:tel,:photo, :old, :description, :password)
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one_attached :photo, dependent: :destroy

  OLD = ['< 1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '> 5']
  validates_inclusion_of :old, :in => OLD
end
```

My logs:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2022-12-08 23:24:42 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"b@b.B", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  TRANSACTION (1.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "b@b.b"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 81)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 8.7ms | Allocations: 6931)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 159)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 21)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 12.9ms | Allocations: 9066)
Completed 200 OK in 247ms (Views: 13.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms | Allocations: 15283)
```

Has anyone any suggestion?
[image]
[image]

I tried to create a def index in users controller, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `allow_nil: true` in your `validates_inclusion_of` validation. This way, your record will become "valid" on sign-up, where you are not sending this parameter:

```rb
validates_inclusion_of :old, in: OLD, allow_nil: true
```